# Given a starting set of nodes and a successors function (node -> Set node), find all the reachable nodes of a graph

Tags: haskell, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I currently have the following implementation, but I'm wondering whether there's a solution that's either faster or doesn't use explicit recursion:

```
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

reachable :: Ord node => Set node -> (node -> Set node) -> Set node
reachable startingNodes successors =
    go startingNodes Set.empty
  where
    go todo checked =
        case Set.minView todo of
            Nothing -> checked
            Just (node, todo') ->
                let new = successors node Set.\\ checked
                    todo'' = todo' `Set.union` new
                    checked' = Set.insert node checked
                in go todo'' checked'
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included test cases so I haven't run this solution on any examples: some bugs are probably lying here and there. But something like this ought to work:

- Write a function `step` which, given a set of visited nodes and set of nodes on the frontier of the explored subgraph, takes one step in all directions on that frontier. The result being a new set of visited nodes and a new frontier.
- use `unfoldr` to repeatedly apply this function thus getting a list of the (growing) sets of visited nodes. The closure is simply the `last` element of that list.

Which is what the following code does:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Reachability where

import Control.Monad (guard)
import Data.List (unfoldr)
import Data.Set (Set, union, empty, (\\))
import qualified Data.Set as Set

reachable' :: forall node. Ord node => Set node -> (node -> Set node) -> Set node
reachable' seed next = last $ seed : unfoldr step (seed, empty) where

  step :: (Set node, Set node) -> Maybe (Set node, (Set node, Set node))
  step (seed, visited) = guard (not $ null seed) >>
    let successors = foldr (union . next) empty seed
        newVisited = visited `union` seed
        newSeed    = successors \\ newVisited
    in return (newVisited, (newSeed, newVisited))
```

Comment: Lovely! The one problem I currently see is that `last` fails when `seed` is empty.

Comment: Good point. I have edited to add `seed` in front of the list generated by the `unfoldr`.